# Openmpi and vargrind

Tags: openmpi, memory-leak-detector

I just use a valgrind to test an example provide in openmpi-1.4/example:

`mpirun.openmpi --np 2 valgrind --log-file=output.dat --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck ./ring_c`

then I found below in output.dat:

> ==30450== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
>
> ==30450==    at 0x54DC150: __writev_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x7E3B312: mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x7E3C50A: mca_oob_tcp_peer_send (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x7E40266: mca_oob_tcp_send_nb (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x7C2FFB7: orte_rml_oob_send (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x7C30637: orte_rml_oob_send_buffer (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x824CBAE: ??? (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4E900FB: ompi_mpi_init (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>   ==30450==    by 0x4EA8499: PMPI_Init (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4009AD: main (ring_c.c:19)
>
> ==30450==  Address 0x65c0321 is 161 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd
>
> ==30450==    at 0x4C2DEAE: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4F1E619: opal_dss_buffer_extend (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4F1E9D0: opal_dss_copy_payload (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4EFA3DD: orte_grpcomm_base_pack_modex_entries (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x824CA8F: ??? (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4E900FB: ompi_mpi_init (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4EA8499: PMPI_Init (in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.8)
>
> ==30450==    by 0x4009AD: main (ring_c.c:19)
>
> ==30450== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==30450==     in use at exit: 298,974 bytes in 1,482 blocks
>
> ==30450==   total heap usage: 7,740 allocs, 6,258 frees, 13,223,431 bytes allocated
>
> ... ... ...
>
> ==30450== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==30450==    definitely lost: 51,132 bytes in 69 blocks
>
> ==30450==    indirectly lost: 14,378 bytes in 39 blocks
>
> ==30450==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==30450==    still reachable: 233,464 bytes in 1,374 blocks
>
> ==30450==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==30450== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>
> ==30450== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
>
> ==30450==
>
> ==30450== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==30450== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialized values come from
>
> ==30450== ERROR SUMMARY: 63 errors from 63 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

It has memory leak based on the memorycheck results. 
Since the example is provided by openmpi-1.4 developers, does it mean every program using openmpi-1.4 as a libary will meet memory leak?
Fred

Comment: In addition to the answer: OpenMPI 1.4 is more than four years old. You might want to consider updating.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons, OpenMPI is not valgrind-clean. However, as per [the FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#valgrind_clean), a supression file is provided.

```
mpirun -np 2 valgrind --suppressions=$PREFIX/share/openmpi/openmpi-valgrind.supp
```